# LightSwitch dynamic cascading dropdown lists

Tags: dynamic, drop-down-menu, recursion, visual-studio-lightswitch, cascading

In lightswitch, I need to make dynamic cascading dropdown lists based on a recursive relationship:

Table "Categories" includes:

1. Id
2. Name
3. ParentId

[image: Categories recursive relationship]
here is the desired scenario:

1. a screen showing a drop down list for the categories with no parent
   (ParentId = Null).
2. once user selects a specific category, another
   drop down to be created which includes the selected category
   children.
3. User can select another child category, and show another
   dynamic dropdown, and so on till we have categories drop down with
   no children.

Thanks & I really appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I miss also tree controls in lightswitch, for this reason, I have developed my own:

- **[LightSwitch Custom Control: Tree CRUD Operations](http://beutil.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/lightswitch-custom-control-tree-crud.html)**
- **[LightSwitch Custom Control: Tree lookup Operations](http://beutil.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/lightswitch-custom-control-tree-loojup.html)**

Be free to get source code and video samples from this links.

Here my [control playing with a 2,4Millions nodes tree](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nPvesAYKn8)